# Removing an array of words from a string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

I have data that includes certain words that I do not want to display. I am trying to remove these set of words from the string before displaying it to the label. With the code I have, I can do this word by word, but have to type out the code X amount of times to achieve it for each word. What would be the correct method to remove the set of words at once?

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
 let remove = ["Production", "Productions", "Studio", "Studios", 
"Entertainment", "Pictures", "Company", "Films", "Media"]
                if let range = string.range(of: remove) {
                    string.removeSubrange(range)
                }
                self.label.text = string
```

With this code I receive this error on the `range` line:

> Argument type '[String]' does not conform to expected type 'StringProtocol'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear.

The argument of `range(of` is a `String` not an array (`[String]`)

You need a loop

```
let wordsToRemove = ["Production", "Productions", "Studio", "Studios", "Entertainment", "Pictures", "Company", "Films", "Media"]
for word in wordsToRemove {
   if let range = string.range(of: word) {
      string.removeSubrange(range)
   }
}
self.label.text = string
```

An alternative is regular expression

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "(Productions?|Studios?|Entertainment|Pictures|Company|Films|Media)",
                                             with: "",
                                          options: .regularExpression)
self.label.text = trimmedString
```

Comment: I preferred the alt expression. Thanks!

Comment: Although the replaced words leave a blank space, even if there isn't a space for `with: ""`. Have a fix for this?

Comment: The code is supposed to work. It doesn't consider a space before or after the word (as well as  the `removeSubrange` solution). If you want to remove also a leading space change the pattern to `"\\s(Productions?|...`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
remove.forEach {
   if let range = string.range(of:$0) {
     string.removeSubrange(range)
  }
}
```

as `range(of:)` expects a string not array

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the allowed words, and then use `Filter` to remove the unwanted words:

```
var strings = ["Hello","Playground","World","Earth"]

var allowedStrings = "Playground Earth" // Specify using space
let seperated:[String] = allowedStrings.components(separatedBy: " ")

for i in seperated {
    if strings.contains(i) {
        strings = strings.filter{$0 != i}
    }
}
print(strings)   // ["Playground", "Earth"]
```